# Modify Hyperlinkfield text in Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I am stumped on this one.  I want to modify the text in a Hyperlinkfield of Gridview after the data is bound to it.  I found similar code to this on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) and I can't get it to work.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[2].Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text + "random text";
    }
```

I also tried similar code in the Page_PreRender event with no luck.  I have also tried calling DataBind() before this one line of code with no help.  I always just get "random text" in the cell without the data from the DB.  Thanks

Comment: With the code you have posted--and nothing in prerender, init, etc. except a call to DataBind(), you get multiple rows with cell 2 filled with "random text"? And if you comment out that line, it's filled with data?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try like...

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    HyperLink hyp = (HyperLink)e.Row.Findcontrol("YourHyperlinkID");
    hyp.Text = "Your New Text";
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a TemplateColumn for that solution

Comment: I tried this, but the Hyperlinkfield does not have an ID property so I cant "find" it with a call to FindControl.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while trying to [figure this out myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509685/cant-access-hyperlinkfield-text-in-a-gridview) (based-on [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176774/get-text-of-asp-net-hyperlinkfield-in-gridview)).  I see this question was from a while ago, but I wanted to answer it in case someone else found it looking for answers.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0].Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0].Text + "random text";
}
```