# Get text of ASP.NET HyperLinkField in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the text of a HyperLinkField in a GridView's OnRowDelete event (the HyperLinkField's text is the primary key of the row I wish to delete). I understand that you can't get the text using the code I've placed below; it only works for BoundFields (for HyperLinkFields, the string is ""). But, I've been unable to find a working answer for getting this text. How do I get the displayed text from a HyperLinkField? (VS2010 w/ ASP.NET 4.0 and C#)

Thanks for reading!

**GridView Design**

```
        <asp:GridView ID="teamGridView" runat="server" CssClass="gridView" RowStyle-CssClass="rowStyle"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="altRowStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="viewsHeader"
        OnRowEditing="Team_OnRowEditing" OnRowDeleting="Team_OnRowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="Team_OnRowUpdating"
        OnRowCancelingEdit="Team_OnRowCancelingEdit">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Team Name" DataTextField="Team Name" DataNavigateUrlFields="Team Name"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Teams.aspx?Team_Name={0}" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Team Captain" DataField="Team Captains" />
            <asp:CommandField Visible="false" HeaderText="Commands" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**GridView Populating Code**

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["***"].ConnectionString))
        {
            // Initialize GridView and data
            teamGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserLevel"]) > 0)
            {

                teamGridView.Columns[2].Visible = true;
            }
            SqlDataAdapter teamDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet teamDataSet = new DataSet();
            if (Request["Team_Name"] == null)
            {
                // Show the list of teams if no specific team is requested
                teamDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("[Team Select]", connection);
                teamDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                teamDataAdapter.Fill(teamDataSet);
                teamGridView.DataSource = teamDataSet;
                teamGridView.DataBind();
            }
}
```

**GridView OnRowDeleting Code**

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["***"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand teamDeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("[Team Delete]", connection);
        teamDeleteCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        teamDeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("TeamName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        teamDeleteCommand.Parameters[0].Value = teamGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
        Response.Write(teamDeleteCommand.Parameters[0].Value);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            teamDeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Team Deletion Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, MVC team, for saving me from this particular brand of hell.

Comment: Does the text already binded to Hyper link field

Comment: @Dorababu yes. I tried this with Cells[1] (a BoundField) and got the string I expected. This is a documented issue with HyperLinkFields, but I haven't been able to find any resolutions in my searches of the web and MSDN.

Comment: Does you take it as Bound field or template field

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking. The field is the HyperLinkField built into ASP.NET.

Comment: Ya that's what i am asking if you bind the hyperlink field inside grid-view in which you bind the data using Item-template or Bound-filed please post your source of grid-view design for more help

Comment: Try by using Datakey Name in grid-view as you said that your primary key value is the text of Hyper-link add datakeyname="your key here"

Comment: This is coding horror. Remove all this SQL from code behind and learn some N-tier layer programming. No free coffee for a member of a team who does programming like this :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of

```
teamGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
```

Try

```
( (HyperLink) teamGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).Text
```

Just can't avoid advising you to change the way you put all SQL directly in your page like this. Try leaning about N tier development. MSDN and asp.NET website and channel9.msdn have good videos to start with. Also, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu

> http://gurustop.net

Comment: DirectCast(teamGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Controls(0), HyperLink).Text - For VB.NET users

Comment: How can this possibly be correct? According to the MSDN documentation, HyperLinkField isn't a Control (despite living in the WebControls namespace) - it derives from DataControlField which in turn derives directly from System.Object.

Comment: We are not dealing with the hyperlink field here. We are dealing with the hyperlink that the hyperlink field adds to the given cell. It worked for the original poster :)

Answer (score 1):

```
((HyperLink)teamGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).Text
```

will give the text or displayed value of the field. Alternatively we can try

```
((HyperLink)teamGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).NavigateUrl
```

for getting the target link.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative method of getting the text value of a hyperlink:

```
Server.HtmlDecode((teamGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] as HyperLink).Text)
```