# Can't access HyperLinkField text in a GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have a HyperLinkField defined as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNotifications" runat="Server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableViewState="true" CssClass="tableWhole" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="tableAlt">
<Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Item#" DataTextField="sku" 
                        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/store/item/{0}/"
                        DataNavigateUrlFields="sku" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemNo" />
```

In my code-behind, I'm attempting to access the Text property like this:

```
    For Each gvRow In gvNotifications.Rows
        processItem(gvRow.Cells(0).Text.ToString)
    Next
```

This code worked when it was defined as a BoundField, like this:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Item #" DataField="sku" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemNo" />
```

How can I access the Text property on a HyperLinkField in a GridView.Row.Cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out based-on a [related C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176774/get-text-of-asp-net-hyperlinkfield-in-gridview).

```
For Each gvRow In gvNotifications.Rows
    processItem(gvRow.Cells(0).Controls(0).Text.ToString)
Next
```