# Can't access the text in the TextArea in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

```
<ItemTemplate>
<textarea ID="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" cols="20" name="S1" rows="2">         </textarea><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName = "comment" Text = "Comment"/>
</ItemTemplate>

 SqlParameter par1 = new SqlParameter("@txt", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        par1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        par1.Value = Request.Form["TextArea1"];
        com.Parameters.Add(par1);
```

I can't get the text in a `textArea` which is in a `gridview`. I just can't access it from the behind code.

I want to assign the text in the `textArea` to a variable but I can't reach the `textArea`

Any ideas?

Comment: If you could, also paste your code-behind where you're trying to assign it.

Comment: I don't see your GridView or your code for how you are iterating through its rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have a sample gridview, It may help you.**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#006699"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#FFFFFF" onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
<Columns >

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="uname" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pass" DataField="upass"/>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>Active</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate >
<asp:TextBox ID="TextArea1" runat="server" TextMode="multiline" Text='<%#Eval("active")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:ButtonField CommandName="comment" Text="comment" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "comment")
  {
    string uname = "";
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
    TextBox txtbox1_val = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextArea1");
    uname = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[1].Text.ToString());
    //write code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I had this (nearly) exact same question a few weeks ago, and solved it here: [Can't access HyperLinkField text in a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509685/cant-access-hyperlinkfield-text-in-a-gridview).

The way I figured it out, was I debugged my code and checked the values from the immediate window.  You'll want to set a breakpoint in the spot in your code where you're iterating through your rows and then check your values (immediate window) like this:

```
?myGridView.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0].Text
```

When you actually assign it, you might need to cast it in order to get it to work:

```
par1.Value = ((TextBox)myGridView.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Comment: yeah when i tried your solution thats what i got
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea as a value so still i do have a problem

Comment: i can see that it reaches the textArea but still dont know how to get the text since the only method i know to get that is toString and as i said above it just return System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea as a value

Comment: Edit your post with your code (what you've tried) so I can take a look at it.